# How to download and show data?

Tags: android, url, android-download-manager

I have a download link like "www.abcd.com/id=778".I may have a pdf,image or docs.I want to download that data and after download compleated I want to open it.
I tried with download manager but get only .bin files

```
        String servicestring = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;
        DownloadManager downloadmanager;
        downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(servicestring);
        Uri uri = Uri
                .parse(input);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader
Simple in terms of implementation.

Comment: I am trying to implement the library but I have an error saying incompatible tyes. Can y help me?